# Trying to connect a dynamically created select element (tag) with options to a dynamically created table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The first block of code is a working example of what I want the variable select to do. the var Select is there to be a td  in the variable tr. the variable tr is used 2 times in this code. once to to append the tr when the table has html and another time when it doesn't have any html. the reason is because if doesn't have html it should append the header and the row with the select element and the rest of the data that's supposed to be on the row and if does have html it should only append the row to prevent repetition of the header. so I would like a nice clean variable named tr that will be append every time the users invokes it. [**jsfidle**](http://jsfiddle.net/49axJ/2/) if you click on the drop down you could select the item and the new row will appear.

```
      $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
         lookup: currencies,
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        var thehtml = '<strong>Item:</strong> ' + suggestion.value + ' <br>      <strong>price:</strong> ' + suggestion.data + "<br>" + suggestion.divs;
        var tableheader = ($("<thead>")
            .append($("<tr>")
                .append($("<th>Item</th><th>Qty</th><th>Price</th>")))
            )
      var select = " <select class = 'select'><option value='volvo>Volvo</option> <option value='saab'>Saab</option>  <option value='mercedes'>Mercedes</option> <option value='audi'>Audi</option> </select>"
  var tr = "<tr><td>"+ suggestion.value + "</td><td>" +select +"</td></tr>"

 if($(".table").html().length <= 0)
 {
    $('.table').append($("<table>")).append(tableheader).append(tr);
}else{
    if($(".table").html().length > 0){
        $(".table").append(tr)
    }

}
```

The thing is I want the select element to be made up dynamically so i tried something and I cant figure out why it wont work. It's not recieving the variable. Am i implementing the varable wrong with the $.each?

```
  $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
lookup: currencies,
onSelect: function (suggestion) {
  var thehtml = '<strong>Item:</strong> ' + suggestion.value + ' <br> <strong>price:</strong> ' + suggestion.data + "<br>" + suggestion.divs;
  var tableheader = ($("<thead>")
            .append($("<tr>")
                .append($("<th>Item</th><th>Qty</th><th>Price</th>")))
            )

var  selectValues = { "3": "2", "2": "1" , "1": "..."};

 var select =  $.each(selectValues, function(key, value){
        $('.select').append($('<option>', {value: value}).text(value));
        // <option value='volvo>Volvo</option>
    });

  var tr = "<tr><td>"+ suggestion.value + "</td><td><select class ='select'>" + select + "</select></td></tr>";



 if($(".table").html().length <= 0)
 {
    $('.table').append($("<table>")).append(tableheader).append(tr);
}else{
    if($(".table").html().length > 0){
        $(".table").append(tr)
    }

}


},
maxHeight:100,
width:600
```

});

thanks for your help

Comment: Can you provide fiddle?

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/49axJ/)  I hope this help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use object if you use only value?
if you realy don't need key juste create an array :

```
var  selectValues = ["2", "1", "..."];
var value;

var select =  selectValues.forEach(function(value){
    $('.select').append($('<option>', {value: value}).text(value));
    // <option value='volvo>Volvo</option>
});
// or if you want more compatibility
for (var i = 0, len = selectValue.length; i < len; i++) {
    value = selectValue[i];
    $('.select').append($('<option>', {value: value}).text(value));
});
```

Edit:
i make some mistake sorry.
first forEach will return nothing so it's can't work.
I test with your fidle. try this (replace by old for loop if you don't want to use map).

```
var select =  selectValues.map(function(value){
    return "<option value=" + value + ">"  + value + "</option>";
    // <option value='volvo>Volvo</option>
}).join('');
```

first you do not have to append from $('.select') because this dom not exist at this moment
and you can't concate an array in a string like this.

Comment: I copied and pasted  your first solution and the numbers in the selectValues array didnt show up but the select el showed.var  selectValues = ["2", "1", "..."];
var value;

var select =  selectValues.forEach(function(value){
    $('.select').append($('<option>', {value: value}).text(value));
    // <option value='volvo>Volvo</option>
});

Comment: i attached the jsfiddle so if you could make the changes to that it will help me out

Comment: Thank you sir, it works. im curious to know why you prefer map and not forEach or $.each I understand that you are returning the string for the option to the select element  in the var tr.  why did you use .join('') in this case. Thank you for your help so far, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: map will convert the array of value to an array of string "<option ..." . and map return this new array so i use join to get a full string and concatain it inside the string you affect to var tr. An other way will be to use for(i=0,len=selectValues.length;i<len;i++) {select += "<option value="+value+">"+value+"</option>";} . but i like using map ;)